# How to present year instead of date in Hyperlink control in webForms

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to show year instade of date string in a HyperLinkField in asp.net WebForms

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Economic year" DataTextField="Date" SortExpression="Date"DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="P_ProfitLossADD.aspx?Id={0}"></asp:HyperLinkField>
```

but HyperLinkField does not take DataFormatString="{0:d} as property of the control .

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Economic year" DataTextField="Date" DataTextFormatString="{0:YYYY}" SortExpression="Date"DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="P_ProfitLossADD.aspx?Id={0}"></asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Comment: Usage documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was expecting it to be selected as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it you can just use

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Economic year">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="Id" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Id", "P_ProfitLossADD.aspx?id={0}") %>'
                                Text='<%# Eval("Date","{0:yyyy}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```